# The notion of "stable mean-field state" of a spin liquid

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, spin-models

I have some issues understanding X-G. Wen's notion of *stable mean-field states* of spin liquids.
I understand that the slave-boson mean-field theory is reliable when fluctuations on top of it are *weak* (i.e., the interactions are irrelevant perturbations).
However, in his [book](https://academic.oup.com/book/25836) (pg. 368) it is claimed that giving the gauge bosons an energy gap yields such a stable state:

> [...] the gauge field can only mediate short-range interactions. As a consequence, the spinons are not confined.

This seems to contradict my understanding of a spin-liquid state as a deconfined phase of a parton gauge theory. Indeed, as explained some pages before this section (pg.359):

> In the confining phase, the spinons interact with each other through a linear potential and can never appear as quasiparticles at low energies. The gauge bosons have a large energy gap in the confining phase and are absent from the low-energy spectrum.

Why does the *stable mean-field state* obtained by giving the gauge bosons a mass then describe a spin-liquid state, which is supposed to have both gauge bosons and spinons as well-defined quasiparticles?